# Save passwords on Android 4.3+ Webview

Tags: android, passwords, android-webview

I have noticed that the webview on Android 4.3+ do not support saving of passwords (or any form data). I have been looking for a few weeks now trying to find a solution but have come to no avail. I am wondering is there an alternative to using this webview? Or is there a way I can force form data to be saved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the Android official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), saving passwords in `WebView` is deprecated in `api level 18+`.

Comment: I've had a look at that. Im wondering, is there no way around it or another. Library of a webview which i can use instead of the built in android webview.